# Latex to XML convertor process

Tags: conversion, latex-misc, xml

I know latex, but new in xslt (learning now), I need to convert the tex to xml file through XSLT (one of my friend suggest, but i failed to convert). Please suggest or give example to convert the files.

Comment: xslt is a language designed for the other direction, it can read xml it can't read a latex file in any useful way. use a convertor such as latexml or tex4ht to generate xml from latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE hope this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/643627/moodle-xml-conversion-to-latex may helpful for you

Answer (score 2):

XSLT is a language designed to take XML as *input* so is not that useful to read latex files although it would be useful to convert an intitial xml conversion to whatever specific xml format you need.

A simple example would be to use `make4ht` to generate xhtml formatted XML.

So, using the standard latex example document `small2e.tex` which is in the base distribution so you can use

`pdflatex small2e`

which makes a small2e.pdf

[image]

or

`make4ht -f xhtml small2e`

which makes an xml file `small2e.html` which displays in a browser as

[image]

Or could be used as the input to an XSLT transformation to convert to a different xml format.